# Multiple XMLHttpRequests not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am puzzled about this. I have two XMLHttpRequests that operate on Select elements of my HTML file (each one operates on a different Select element right when the HTML file is loaded). I am using a callback function as was recommended on W3CSchools. If my variable xmlHttp is defined outside of my callback function, only the second request works, and the first one gets deleted before it has a chance to finish. If I put 'var' in front of it the same thing happens. *However*, if my variable is inside the function with 'var' in front of it, then absolutely nothing happens. I have narrowed it down to where to the line that says "HERE!!!!!" is where  the program seems to hang. I know the loadXMLDoc function does not actually finish because when I put an alert outside of it, nothing happens. I am supposing it has something to do with the 'if' part and the program not being able to recognize xmlHTTP, even though it was locally defined. I am still pretty new to JavaScript and just want to be able to run multiple XMLHttpRequest objects at once without them getting in each other's way but also without the page hanging. Any ideas why this does not work?

HTML:

```
<form>

    <select id="stateSelectCities">
        <!-- Will be populated with MySQL -->
    </select>

    <select id="citySelect">
        <option>Select a State</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />

    <select id="stateSelectCounties">
        <!-- Will be populated with MySQL -->
    </select>

    <select id="countySelect">
        <option>Select a State</option>
    </select>

    <p id="xmltest"></p>
    <p id="currentState"></p>
    <p id="sc"></p>
    <p id="rs"></p>
    <p id="st"></p>

</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(method, data, url, cfunc) {
            var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = cfunc;
            xmlHTTP.open(method, url, true);
            if (data) {
                xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHTTP.send(data);
            } else {
                xmlHTTP.send();
            }
        }

function returnStateListForCounties() {
            loadXMLDoc('GET', null, "stateslist.xml", function() {
                document.getElementById('countySelect').disabled = true;
                if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200) {

                    // Read the XML Data and Populate Counties States Menu
                    var response = xmlHTTP.responseXML;
                    var states = response.getElementsByTagName('state');
                    for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.innerHTML = states[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        option.setAttribute('onmouseup', 'returnCounties(this.innerHTML)');
                        document.getElementById("stateSelectCounties").add(option);
                    }
                }
                //document.getElementById("sc").innerHTML = 'statusCode: ' + xmlHTTP.status;
                //document.getElementById("rs").innerHTML = 'readyState: ' + xmlHTTP.readyState;
                //document.getElementById("st").innerHTML = 'statusText: ' + xmlHTTP.statusText;

            })
        }

function returnStateListForCities() {
            loadXMLDoc('GET', null, 'stateslist.xml', function() {
                document.getElementById('citySelect').disabled = true;
                // HERE!!!!!
                if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200) {

                    // Read the XML Data and Populate Cities States Menu
                    var response = xmlHTTP.responseXML;
                    var states = response.getElementsByTagName('state');
                    for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.innerHTML = states[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        option.setAttribute('onmouseup', 'returnCities(this.innerHTML)');
                        document.getElementById("stateSelectCities").add(option);
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("sc").innerHTML = 'statusCode: ' + xmlHTTP.status;
                document.getElementById("rs").innerHTML = 'readyState: ' + xmlHTTP.readyState;
                document.getElementById("st").innerHTML = 'statusText: ' + xmlHTTP.statusText;

            })
        }

//returnStateListForCounties();
returnStateListForCities();

</script>
```

Comment: id are unique. You have 3 select with the same id.

Comment: @rogelio Thank you for catching that. I have updated the HTML portion. There are a total of 4 select elements (with unique ID's), 2 of which I want to change for now.

Comment: can you copy the url to the w3cschools site (function reference)?

Comment: Yes. It is http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp at the bottom of the page titled "Using a Callback Function". I tried their "Try it Yourself" button, and tried to put their 'var xmlhttp' inside the function, and it did not work on their site either. I redid my function to make sure all the onreadystatechanges were in loadXMLDoc rather than outside of it so that the xmlhttp variable could be accessed when it is local. Thankfully it worked. I am not sure why they say to do it that way on W3C Schools especially when the variable has to be global their way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `xmlHTTP` variable which is defined inside `loadXMLDoc` function and try to use again inside `returnStateListForCounties` function, I'll do it like this:

```
       function loadXMLDoc(method, data, url, cfunc) {
            var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200)
                {                         
                    cfunc(xmlHTTP.responseXML); //Call passed func with the resulting XML
                }
            };

            xmlHTTP.open(method, url, true);
            if (data) {
                xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHTTP.send(data);
            } else {
                xmlHTTP.send();
            }
        }
```

This way you encapsulate the data recovery.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is what I had suspected, although I was hoping that wasn't the case. I'll play around with this encapsulation a bit.

Comment: Thank you Balder! This was a lifesaver. I put all my onreadystatechange functions into loadXMLDoc and it worked nicely. I was able to access the local variable, and thus make several copies of it as needed without the calls getting in each other's way.